# Create new, grouped conditional variable in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, grouping, tidyverse

Im trying to create a new variable, which is grouped and has several conditions underlying it.
E.g. using the iris dataset:

I want to add a new column, grouped by species and contains information about the size. The outcome is expected to be a factor variable with levels "small", "medium" and "large".

Here's an example:

```
data(iris)
data %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Species) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Size =
                  if_else(Sepal.Length <= 5.1 ~ "small",
                          Sepal.Length <= 5.8 & > 5.1 ~ "medium",
                          Sepal.Length > 5.8 ~ "large")
                )
```

It doesn't work. Apparently there's

> an unmatched closed bracket ")"

Now, I am aware of other solutions, e.g. using Base R's ifelse function, but I'm trying to find an elegant way to express myself using tidyverse-style code. Can anyone help?
I would be happy about any solutions using tidyverse code. Doesn't matter what function it is.

Comment: In the `if_else` statement I don't see it relative to group variables `Species` what do you mean by a grouped variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few syntax errors. Try :

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  mutate(Size = case_when(Sepal.Length <= 5.1 ~ "small",
                          Sepal.Length <= 5.8 & Sepal.Length > 5.1 ~ "medium",
                          Sepal.Length > 5.8 ~ "large"))
```

I understand this is just an example but if you want to divide data into different range of buckets you can also consider `?cut` and `?findInterval`.

```
iris$Size <- cut(iris$Sepal.Length, c(-Inf, 5.1, 5.8, Inf),
                c('small', 'medium', 'large'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ronak. This was tremendously helpful. I wasn't familiar with the `cut` function, but, I'm definitely going to look into is, as I think from what I saw from it now, it might be an even more elegant solution. Please feel encouraged to offer a solution using the `cut` function, as it doesn't look like this is among tidyverse's most popular functions. Also, while I was researching to find solved topics for my problem, I noted there really isn't much around on the internet, while quite some people appear have posted similar requests. Kind regards.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how you can use `cut` here.